# Sharepoint development can only be done on Server OS?

Tags: development-enviroment

We're on Visual Studio 2013 and Sharepoint 2013. So in Visual Studio I click new project Empty Sharepoint Solution. It says:

"The required version of Sharepoint Foundation 2013 or Sharepoint Server 2013 is not installed on this system..."

They give a link too, which I followed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

This tells me that you have to have Sharepoint locally installed to developer for Sharepoint and the article tells me that Sharepoint 2013 can only be installed on Server OS's.

Is microsoft trying to tell me that I'd have to license each of my developers with an additional Server and Sharepoint license to develop small sharepoint apps?

Comment: Apps are not SharePoint Solutions, for that you can live with an Office 365 developer site. But for other types of solutions (farm solutions) you need SharePoint locally installed

Comment: And, get an msdn subscription, which would include VS and all server products, such as sql and sharepoint, instead of actual server licenses.

Comment: @RobertLindgren what is the difference between apps and solutions then? What would you do with a Solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to develop farm solutions, you need to have SharePoint installed on the machine Visual Studio is running on.  With SharePoint 2013, you have to use Windows Server.  2013 cannot be installed on Windows 7 or 8 (like 2010 could).

As far as Apps for SharePoint are concerned, you do not need SharePoint installed.  You just need a remove SharePoint 2013 server to connect to.

Comment: Thanks @John. So what is the major between developing a Sharepoint solution vs apps?

Comment: There are pretty significant differences between the two. Do some pretty thorough research and testing before committing to one or the other. (Or really, a developer should know both, as there is not 100% overlap between the two.)

Comment: Like Mike2500 said, they have some pretty significant differences.  I would start here to learn more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163114(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the managed client side object model

You don't need to have sharepoint installed. A good example would be a desktop application or mobile solution. This will give you more range then an App.